# Trigonometry and collisions/reflection in Pong game

Tags: reflection, pygame, trigonometry, collision, pong

For fun I am making Pong in Python with Pygame. I have run into some trouble with reflections.

So the ball has an angle associated with it. Since positive y is down this angle is downward. If the ball hits the top or bottom walls I can simply negate the angle and it will reflect properly, but the trouble is with the left and right walls. I cannot figure out the trigonometry for how to change the angle in this case. I am currently trying combinations of the below snippet but with no luck.

```
 self.angle = -(self.angle - math.pi/2)
```

I have attached the code. You can try it for yourself easily. Just remember to take out the "framerate" module which I have not included or used yet. I would appreciate any input. Thanks!

Comment: The code is here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7264839/code/pong.py

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to look into [Angle of Incidence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_of_incidence).

[image]

Basically you'll want to find the angle *theta* between your incoming vector and the normal of the wall the ball is hitting. Where the incoming angle is (wall normal)-*theta* the resulting angle is  (wall normal)+*theta*.

The angle can be found using the dot product between your incoming vector and the normal of the wall, then taking the inverse cosine (normalize your vectors first).

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
math.pi - angle
```